# Make cmd after an X amount of seconds in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make the console window close after an X amount of seconds here's an example:

My program says "Type in a number:"

Then I type "1945"

After I type the number the console says "Unlocked".

The problem is that I want the console to re-run the original message after 3-4 seconds so that it just continuously will do this in a loop.

Down below I have included the current code with comments on where I want it do do my wanted things.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace portkod
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kod:");

        int kod = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        DateTime tiden = DateTime.Now;



        if (kod == 1946)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            //After this message comes up I want the program to ask for "Kod:"
            //again after like 3-4 seconds.

            Console.WriteLine("Unlocked!");
        }
        else if (kod != 1946)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Locked!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this.

The GetIntFromConsole reads from the console, and only returns a nr when a valid integer was given, if not asks at once again.

As long as the user doesn't give in 1946, the program repeats the question after 4 seconds, and marks 'Locked'

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Repeat
{
    class Program
    {
        static int GetIntFromConsole(string label)
        {
            int result;
            string input;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("{0}: ", label);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!int.TryParse(input, out result));
            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result;
            result = GetIntFromConsole("Kod");
            while (result != 1946)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Locked");
                Thread.Sleep(4000); // 4 seconds = 4000 milliseconds
                result = GetIntFromConsole("Kod");
            } 
            Console.WriteLine("Unlocked");
        }
    }
}
```

As requested, i will try to explain a bit more

the GetIntFromConsole can be called from anywhere inside the program, and will return only a valid parsed integer, that means empty strings, or anything else than numbers will not parse correctly, and the user will have to retry

The loop used here, is the do { this logic } while (condition is met)

This means, when you are using a do / while loop you will always enter this loop, until the condition after while returns false

The while loop inside the Main, checks a condition first, and if this one is true, it goes into the loop, if not it skips forward to Console.WriteLine("Unlocked").

in case you want to run a continuous loop as mentioned in your comments below, you can to it in the following way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int result;
    while (true)  // always true, it will always repeat
    {
        result = GetIntFromConsole("Kod");
        while (result != 1946)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Locked");
            Thread.Sleep(4000); // 4 seconds = 4000 milliseconds
            result = GetIntFromConsole("Kod");
        } 
        Console.WriteLine("Unlocked");
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
}
```

this new while loop will loop until you issue a `break;` statement, since it restarts the logic again from on: `result = GetIntFromConsole("Kod");` your result will be re-evaluated and you can lock / unlock the screen again a few times ;)

I hope that was a sufficient explanation, i'm not very much of a teacher :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think you could take some time to explain what the code does? As I'm trying to learn it would be fun to learn how the different elements work and how they communicate :D

Comment: Also how do I make it loop after it unlocks? I've added so that after 4 seconds of being unlocked it goes back to "Kod:" but how do I make it so that I can type "1946" in there so that the same methods are called again?

Comment: So, you would like to have an endless loop asking for the code, and locking or unlocking it? What would you like to have more explained?

Comment: Yes exactly, like and entry code.

I'd like to know how the GetIntFromConsole method, it seems really complicated from the eyes of a beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thread.Sleep to wait some time.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (getKod() != 1946)
    {

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Unlocked");
}


static int getKod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Kod:");
    int kod;
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out kod);
    return kod;
}
```

Comment: your getKod should be static if it's called from a static method